# Using DLNA certified smart TV as an external monitor for Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, external-display, dlna

In general would be possible to start DLNA (server I guess) on Linux laptop which will be sharing/mirroring/cloning/extending ... laptop's desktop to Smart TV (which will act as a DLNA client I guess) if the TV is claimed to use DLNA certificate? [This](http://realmike.org/blog/2015/05/27/wip-mirror-your-linux-desktop-to-your-tv/) article I've found sounds promising.